# How can I make a button be a label for hidden input in React with Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So, I want to create a button to change avatar in my app. I use hidden file input and wanted to make a button to be a label for it, so user would click a button and choose the avatar instead of inputting to file input. Here is my code:

```
<Grid container spacing={2} direction="column" className={classes.avatarArea}>
  <Grid item>
    <Avatar alt={getCookie("name")} src={avatar} className={classes.avatar}>{getCookie("name").charAt(0)}</Avatar>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    <Input
      style={{ display: 'none' }}
      id="avatar-file-input"
      type="file"
      accept="image/*"
      onChange={uploadAvatar} />
    <label htmlFor="avatar-file-input">
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.iconButton} startIcon={<CloudUploadIcon />}>Change avatar</Button>
    </label>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

However, button doesn't work as label. If I change button with, for example, avatar(so that user need to click on the avatar to change it), everything works great. So, it seems that the problem is with button itself.
How can I set up button as label for the input?